# Can you backup installed applications to an external hard drive, then restore them to another Computer without Reinstalling them?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Can you backup installed applications to an external hard drive, then restore them to another Computer without Reinstalling them? For example, My computer Windows 7 Home Premium has many softwares, applications, programs, utilities, etc.. That i purchased and dont want to Reinstall them on new computer. Is it possible for them to work without Re-entry keys? Any help I will appreciate

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1137/why-arent-all-applications-portable

Comment: Yes, this is possible, involves duplicating the hdd.  The problem of course is license for Windows limits you, since the license your currently using cannot be transfered to another computer.  Why don't you just reinstall the applications?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reinstall them all over again, as most of the program licences are limited, and this way you could copy them to many computers.

Answer (score -1):

- I thought Super ISO would do the job;

  - nero multimedia suit 10
    (select secure disc CD/DVD-main bord will find it automatic, it`s
    plug and play)
- for ASUS laptops/desktops it`s asus backtracker -->[enter link
  description here](http://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1008641/) then you select which windows you have 32/64 bits (laptops x64 after 2013).

**Don`t forget to format (first save data then right click->format) your stick to fat 32 before downloading file.**

Have a nice day,
*George Andrew-memeber since today 2016/10/16*

Comment: I cannot see how this even tries to answer the question. You just name some programs and that's it. Neither does what the OP wants anyway.